# Why would Old Gen get more committed memory than it needs?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

The following is happening in my application:

Eden space commits, uses, and releases memory quickly, as one would expect.  Survivor space uses an incredibly small amount of memory, and its committed memory matches that directly.  Old Gen used space is a bit larger (1-2 gigs), but is incredibly stable.  This all makes sense - most objects come and go very quickly, and a select few hang around for the full application lifetime.

However, the space *committed* for Old Gen spikes like crazy, often multiple times above what is currently used in both Old Gen and Survivor space *combined*.  Additionally, despite these spikes, the used space is rock-solid - no variation at all.

My question is two-fold:

1. What might cause allocation spikes in Old Gen that never actually get filled?
2. In general, why would Old Gen ever allocate more space than [Old Gen used]+[Survivor used]?

Comment: sizing decisions depend on the collectors, you did not mention which are you using. you did not even provide logs that match your prose. so provide more data. try logging with `-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy` and see if it provides insight.

Comment: How did you collect your data? Please provide information about your tool or API. What do you mean under committed and spike? Are you talking about OS level commit or JVM level commit? Also provide JVM settings and logs if possible.